# Flutter: iOS build fails

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter

I have an issue with Flutter. I can't run my app on an iOS simulator. I've tried to create a new certificate under the Mac keychain and that didn't help me much. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

```
(base) seroaslan@Seros-MBP Desktop % flutter doctor   
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale da-DK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.1.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

(base) seroaslan@Seros-MBP tutorial % flutter run             

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  

 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           2,8s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         3,0s
Xcode build done.                                            9,2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/seroaslan/Desktop/tutorial/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app: resource fork, Finder
    information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Comment: Run flutter doctor and add that to your question as well as try connecting to a different device.

Comment: Hey. It does work on an Android device/simulator. Like you've asked, I have pasted flutter doctor from the terminal. I used 4 hours to solve this problem and I don't know how.

Comment: I’ve posted an answer that should fix this. Just make sure when you are setting it all up again you read through each step carefully so you don’t miss any.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your flutter doctor:

✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

You will need to fix these issues by setting it all up again as shown here: https://flutter.io/setup-macos/